# Scroll only one section of form in access

Tags: microsoft-access, scrolling, forms

Lets say my Access form has 4 quadrants (a=++, b=-+, c=--, d=+-).
I want to have something like a freeze pane utility in the form so that I only scroll b and c quadrants and a and d quadrant's elements stay on the page while scrolling b and c.
I also want to explore other possibilities of freezing sections of the form page.

So basically what I am doing is dividing the Form page into two sections (Left and Right). I should be able to scroll Left part while right part of the form stays in place.

This is a form and not a report (it allows data entry and edits).

Is this possible at all in MS-Access 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add forms as sub-forms to other forms. Just drag and drop a form from the navigation pane to the main form being in design view.

Set the properties of the sub-forms `Record Selector = No` and `Navigation Buttons = No` and set `Scroll Bars` to the desired value. Now, the sub-forms act as separate panes having each their own scroll bars.

In the main form, select the sub-forms and set their `Special Effect` to `Flat` and choose the `Line/Border Color` as `Transparent` (if you don't want a border).

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I am sure that it will solve the issue, but is there any utility like freezing panes/sections on the form in Access, I am saying this because this form that I am trying to work with has a lot of code in it (camera utility and some other if loops), sub-forms will introduce redoing a lot of code.

Comment: Compared to .NET WinForms or WPF, Access forms have a very limited set of controls. In Access sub-forms is the closest to what UserControls or different kinds Panels would provide in .NET.  I really don't see another option. But it is easy to call main form's subroutines that are public from the sub-from, through the `Parent` property. So that might make it easier to refactor your form.

Comment: alright, I am gonna try it. Hopefully its not a lot of work. ;)